# Qt utf-8 encoding issue

Tags: utf-8, qt5

```
    #include <iostream>

    #include <QString>

    using namespace std;
    
    int main()
    {
    
        QString qstr = QString::fromUtf8("      ");
        cout << qstr.length() << std::endl;
        for (QChar c : qstr) cout << QString(c).toStdString() << endl;
    }
```

Got output:

> 19
>
> ?
>
> ?
>
> ?
>
> ?
>
> ?
>
> ?
>
> ?
>
> ?
>
> ?
>
> ?
>
> ?
>
> ?
>
> ?
>
> ?
>
> ?
>
> ?

Expected output:

> 11

Qt version:

> Package: qt5-default Architecture: amd64 Version:
> 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.7 Multi-Arch: same Priority: optional Section: universe/libs Source: qtbase-opensource-src Origin: Ubuntu

How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> QString stores a string of 16-bit QChars
> https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html

"       "
string has 4 byte char.
following code can be used:

```
QString str = QString::fromUtf8("      ");
cout << "uint 32b: " << str.toUcs4().size() << endl;


foreach (const uint &  ucsChar, str.toUcs4())
    cout << QChar::decomposition(ucsChar).toStdString() << endl;
```